# The way to get the same answer by binom.test or prop.test

Tags: r

I'd like to get the same answer by binom.test or prop.test in R for the following question. How can I get the same answer of my manual calculation(0.009903076)?

n=475, H0:p=0.05, H1:p>0.05
What is the probability of phat>0.0733?

```
n <- 475
p0 <- 0.05
p <- 0.0733
(z <- (p - p0)/sqrt(p0*(1 - p0)/n))
# [1] 2.33
(ans <- 1 - pnorm(z))
# [1] 0.009903076
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this from `prop.test()`:

```
prop.test(n*p, n, p0, alternative="greater", correct=FALSE)
# data:  n * p out of n, null probability p0
# X-squared = 5.4289, df = 1, p-value = 0.009903
# alternative hypothesis: true p is greater than 0.05
# 95 percent confidence interval:
# 0.05595424 1.00000000
# sample estimates:
#     p 
# 0.0733 
#
```

You can't get the result from `binom.test()` so far as I can tell because `n*p` is not an integer, it's 34.8175.  The `binom.test()` function only takes an integer values number of successes, so when you convert this to 35 by rounding, `p` effectively becomes 0.07368421, which makes the rest of your results not match.  Even if you had a situation where `n*p` was an integer, `binom.test()` would still not produce the same answer because it's not using a normal approximation as your original code does - it's using the binomial distribution to calculate the probability above `p0`.

Comment: That's a perfect answer! very helpful. Thank you very much.